# How to efficiently create subfolders using Storage Access Framework?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I'm currently using the below code to create subfolder in MicroSD on Lollipop using SAF

```
    String[] folders = fullFolderName.replaceFirst(UriFolder + "/", "").split("/");
    //fullFolderName is a String which represents full path folder to be created 
    //Here fullFolderName = /storage/MicroSD/MyPictures/Wallpapers
    ///storage/MicroSD/MyPictures/ already exists
    //Wallpapers is the folder to be created
    //UriFolder is String and contains /storage/MicroSD
    //folders[] will have folders[0]="MyPictures" folders[1]="Wallpapers"

    DocumentFile Directory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(treeUri));
    //treeUri is the uri pointing to /storage/MicroSD
    //treeUri is a Uri converted to String and Stored so it needs to parsed back to Uri
    DocumentFile tempDirectory = Directory;

    //below loop will iterate and find the MyPictures or the parent
    //directory under which new folder needs to be created
    for(int i=0; i < folders.length-1; i++)
    {
        for(DocumentFile dir : Directory.listFiles())
        {
            if(dir.getName() != null && dir.isDirectory())
            {
                if (dir.getName().equals(folders[i]))
                {
                    tempDirectory = dir;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Directory = tempDirectory;
    }

    Directory.createDirectory(folders[folders.length-1]);
```

The above code works fine and creates subdirectory but it takes ~5 Secs to create the folder. I'm new to SAF so is this the only way to locate subdirectories or is there any other efficient way to create subdirectories?

On internal storage I will use

```
new File(fullFolderName).mkdir();
```

Which will create folder in a fraction of second.

Comment: `//treeUri is the uri pointing to /storage/MicroSD`. It looks more like a String. As why would you parse an uri in the statement above it?

Comment: Remove the second for loop. You can remove all code from the body of the first for loop. Then place `Directory.createDirectory(folders[i]);` in it. Remove the last statement as it is now in the loop. Remove the `-1` from the iterator.

Comment: Hmm i believe i understood you wrong. You want a kind of mkdirs()? And there is only mkdir()? So you have to implement mkdirs() yourself? Please reformat your code block so we dont have to scroll every time to the right to see the paths.

Comment: It looks now to me that you want to create the directory `/storage/MicroSD/MyPictures/Wallpapers`. And upon now only `/storage/MicroSD` exists. Is that all?

Comment: @greenapps , reformatted the question, /storage/MicroSD/MyPictures/ already exist only Wallpapers directory need to be created under  /storage/MicroSD/MyPictures/.

Comment: Then what is the problem? And what is the value and type of treeUri?

Comment: @greenapps , treeUri is a string(Uri converted to string) which is parsed again to Uri. The above code works fine but takes quite sometime to iterate and to get to the child folder, efficiency decrease as the number of child folders increase.

Comment: For the third time: What does treeUri contain? What is it's value.? Your code is much to complicated for such a simple task.

Comment: @greenapps , as mentioned in the above code --> treeUri is the uri pointing to /storage/MicroSD which is actually picked by the user. Please go through the question completely once.

Comment: 'treeUri is the uri pointing to /storage/MicroSD'. ??? treeUri was a string you said. Now is the value/contents of that String "/storage/MicroSD" ? Then why not simply  say so as that was all i was asking for. Further your code is not complete if you do not start with one clean treeUri and show us where folderNames comes from and what it has to do with treeUri.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit efficient way to create

```
public static boolean createFolderUsingUri(String fullFolderName,String treeUri,
                                           String UriFolder,Context ctx)
{
    String[] folders = fullFolderName.replaceFirst(UriFolder + "/", "").split("/");

//fullFolderName is a String which represents full path folder to be created 
//Example: fullFolderName = /storage/MicroSD/MyPictures/Wallpapers
//The path /storage/MicroSD/MyPictures/ already exists 
//Wallpapers is the folder to be created
//UriFolder is String and contains string like /storage/MicroSD
//folders[] will have folders[0]="MyPictures" folders[1]="Wallpapers"
//treeUri string representation of Uri /storage/MicroSD 
//Ex: treeUri content://uritotheMicroSdorSomepath.A33%0A

    DocumentFile Directory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(ctx, Uri.parse(treeUri));

    for(int i=0; i < folders.length-1; i++)
    {
        Directory=Directory.findFile(folders[i]);
    }

    Directory.createDirectory(folders[folders.length-1]);
    return true;
}
```

The method described in question took ~5 Secs, whereas this method takes ~ 3 Secs. On CM file manage the folder creation on same path took ~4 Secs so this is comparatively faster method. Yet searching more faster way which will take < 1 Sec